# Questions in Discrete Mathematics- help needed

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose that each male/female pair of rabbits in a farm produces two new male/female pairs of rabbits at the age of 1 month and six new male/female pairs of rabbits at the age of 2 months and every month afterward. Assume that there is only one male/female pair of rabbits at the beginning of a year. Further assume that no rabbits die in the farm. Let an be the number of male/female pair of rabbits in the farm at the end of month n.

a)  Determine a recurrence relation for an and clearly justify your answer.

b)  By solving the recurrence relation in a) find the number of male/female pairs of rabbits in the farm at the end of month n.

c)  Prove the result in b) by strong mathematical induction.

Am I right?

> [image: image1]
>   [image: image2]

Comment: I got that $a_{-1}=0$, $a_0=1$ and then$$a_n=3a_{n-1}+4a_{n-2}\quad n\ge1$$$$a_n=\frac15(4^n-(-1)^n)\quad n\ge0$$

Comment: @Peter Foreman For question a?

Comment: For parts a and b respectively.

Comment: How about part b and c? It looks I do it wrong